# stranger vs strange man

Tags: ambiguity

Take the following examples:

```
That's a stranger.

That's a strange man.
```

Can these be synonymous? Or does the latter always mean the same as 'weird man'?

Synonyms of 'strange' can be 'unfamiliar' or 'alien', however I can not find examples of sentence number 2 anywhere where they are not meant in the context of 'weird' or 'peculiar'.

And secondly if they *can* mean the same, would a native speaker ever use 'strange man' rather than 'stranger'? Examples appreciated.

Comment: I think "That's a strange man" would always mean 'peculiar', but someone might say, for example "I came home and found a strange man in my house" meaning 'a man I didn't know'.

Comment: @KateBunting Simple enough! Seems like a good example to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sure, strange man could (rarely) mean stranger

**History**

In older use, **strange man** could mean **stranger**, since *strange* meant unfamiliar, alien, or unknown. For instance, in a retelling of the story of *Huon of Bourdeaux* from 1601 (via [Early English Books Online](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A03886.0001.001/1:4.26?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=strange%20man)), the hero enters a new city and talks to a man he is unfamiliar with. After a few exchanges where he is referred to in pronoun form ("quoth he"), this statement is made:

> Sir, (quoth the **strange man**) séeing it is so, for the loue of God I shall bring you to a lodging, whereas you shalbe well and honestly lodged, in a good mans house that beléeueth in God, named Gonder, he is Prouost of the City, and well beloued with the Duke.

This almost certainly is the equivalent of saying "stranger" - the speaker is a man in a town foreign to the hero who the hero doesn't know. This usage of *stranger* is common in late medieval and early modern English texts.

---

**Today**

Similar usage is less likely now, as *strange* (adjective) has semantically shifted. It more often refers to someone abnormal or odd. Specific to *strange man*, *stranger* would be a more efficient way to refer to someone unknown.

In the rare occasions where *strange man* is used to refer to a stranger, it feels more emphatic. Here's J. R. Ripley's *[Buried in Beignets](https://books.google.com/books?id=UwTHCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT12&ots=q9X88hQs7C&dq=But%20even%20though%20he%20was%20a%20fellow%20shop%20owner%2C%20I%20barely%20knew%20the%20man.%20I%20didn%27t%20want%20to%20be%20inviting%20some%20strange%20man%20into%20my%20storeroom%20this%20early%20in%20our%20relationship.&pg=PT12#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, dug out from over 300 results of *strange man* referring to an odd fellow:

> But even though he was a fellow shop owner, I barely knew the man. I didn't want to be inviting **some strange man** into my storeroom this early in our relationship.

"Some strange man" seems to be a common form of emphasis when they're a stranger and not abnormal or peculiar. Here's a transcript from a 2015 show Primetime Live, that I found on [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) after fine-tuning my search:

> JOHN QUIONES (ABC NEWS) It becomes a family affair when my own son puts his girlfriend to the test. The question? How will these unsuspecting significant others react to an overly flirtatious waiter?
>
> TOMMIE# Yo.
>
> JOHN QUIONES (ABC NEWS) (Voiceover) Remember Tommie?
>
> TOMMIE# **Some strange man** is flirting with my wife in front of me, and if I wasn't such a nice person I'd (censored by network) I'd stab him with the damn butter knife.

With that additional insight, I can found other examples meaning *stranger*, including this from Google Books:

> Oh, Emily, you talking crazy. You know as well as I do that in this world we live in it's close to suicide to just strike up a conversation with **some strange man** on the street. (*[Ugly Ways](https://books.google.com/books?id=JaDGy5P34vIC&pg=PT235&dq=Oh,%20Emily,%20you%20talking%20crazy.%20You%20know%20as%20well%20as%20I%20do%20that%20in%20this%20world%20we%20live%20in%20it%27s%20close%20to%20suicide%20to%20just%20strike%20up%20a%20conversation%20with%20some%20strange%20man%20on%20the%20street.%20I&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9jNOOg-rlAhUxWN8KHShwC8cQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by Tina McElroy Ansa)

One other detail: the gender of the person is important in all of these present-day cases. A woman is speaking in the first and third cases, suggesting  a real risk posed by talking to **men** who are unknown. In the second case, a man expresses feeling threatened when an unknown **man** flirts with his wife. So the emphasis in **strange man** (meaning *stranger*) seems to be on his gender as much as his unfamiliarity.

That said, note that *strange man* is much less common than *stranger*, and *some strange man* is less common still. So we're discussing a small percentage of cases when **strange man** is used.

Comment: Very neat and detailed answer, thank you for clarifying.